# SED Replace Matching Line but not if it's commented out

Tags: linux, sed

My text contains a line like this:

`DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"`

There are other lines containing `#DHCPD_INTERFACE=`

I want to replace the whole line `DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"` matching on `DHCPD_INTERFACE=` but not if the line contains a `#`

I've tried:
`sed -i.bak '/^#/!s/DHCPD_INTERFACE=/DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth2"/g' dhcpd`

But this doesn't replace the whole line.

This `DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"` should be updated to `DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth2"`  but no line containing a `#` and `DHCPD_INTERFACE=` should be changed.

How can I do this.. ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anchor(`^`) to match the beginning of the line:

```
sed 's/^\(DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth\)4"/\12"/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first replace the lines with a '#', then replace the lines with "eth4", and finally get back the ones with the '#'.

```
    sed -i.bak s/#DHCPD_INTERFACE=/foo/g dhcpd
    sed -i s/DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"/DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth2"/g dhcpd
    sed -i s/foo/#DHCPD_INTERFACE=/g dhcpd
```

Not the best solution, but still a working one. Hope I helped !

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** solution:

The exemplary `test` file contents:

```
DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"
#DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"
```

---

```
sed 's/\([^#]\|^\)DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"/\1DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth2"/g' test
```

The output:

```
DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth2"
#DHCPD_INTERFACE="eth4"
```

Comment: Thanks thats seems to be perfect.